# How to Style this table-like structure

Tags: html, css

I have this kind of table:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Count A</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Count B</td><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm new to CSS but from what I've read so far I'm assuming that the html should be:

```
<div id="counts-container">
     <div class="count">
         <div class="count-label">Count A</div><div class="count-number">12</div>
     </div>
     <div class="count">
         <div class="count-label">Count B</div><div class="count-number">8</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

It seems to me that I'm on the right track but I'm not sure about how to write the CSS for this html structure.  Any suggestion I appreciate.

---

Ok, so I just want to confirm with you guys.  This table should be:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Count A</th><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Count B</th><td>8</td><tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Table looks fine to me as it is, why not keep it as a table?

Comment: One could argue that your data is tabular and the table is justified. The problem with your div approach is that labels of different length will push the counts aside and misalign. Use a table when the data is tabular, thats what the table is for. :)

Comment: If you have tabular data use a table.

Comment: I think that this is not a tabular structure because from my understanding a table is not horizontal, it is vertical.

Comment: @SBel: Who said tables have to be vertical (i.e. have rows)?

Comment: @SBel — A table consists of a bunch of rows (where everything in a row has something in common that isn't shared with data in another row) and columns (where everything in a column has ditto). The direction doesn't really matter. Organising it vertically lets you use `<thead>`, but that's the only benefit. (You can, and should, still use `<th scope="...">` with a horizontally arranged table).

Comment: Hmm, I thought that the table header <th> is applied vertically.  Should in this the first column consist of table headers as opposed to the first row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case using a `<table>` is ok - just structure it correctly:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Count A</th><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Count B</th><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

`<th>` being the table header cell.

If you are confused about when to use tables and when not I suggest you to consult the specification http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html

Answer (score 1):

If this is tabular data than just go ahead and use a `table`. Thats what that HTML element is supposed to be used for.

`div`'s are for page layout, `table`'s are for displaying tabular data.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm

Comment: Isn't all data in a table tabular data by definition? Therefore, how can anybody misuse a table... hmmm, catch 22 ;)

Comment: Ha hmm I wouldn't say so. I've always seen tabular data as something which with columns and rows, where a column is a field, and a row is  a record, and they all relate. If you have a 2*2 table displaying news in one, gallery images in another, contact form in the 3rd, and a quick links section in the 4th, I wouldn't consider this tabular data.

Comment: I would consider it data in a table though

Comment: @musefan - which is not the same... use your common sense.

Comment: @easwee: If one did use common sense, one might notice I am not seriously suggesting they are the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using a `<table>` tag. Sites that say they're bad really mean "abusing them for formatting reasons instead of using padding and margins is bad".

But if you're set on using `<div>`s, try this:

```
#counts-container {display: table;}
.count {display: table-row;}
.count-label, .count-number {display: table-cell;}
```

Comment: Removing a table to replace it with divs that behave like a table.... Brilliant! :D

Comment: I knew somebody was going to suggest that!

Comment: Note that `display:table` has limited browser support - IE7 and below won't grab it.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, I've seen it done plenty of times. Not by me, though ;)

Answer (score -1):

counts-container becomes your table,
count becomes your row,
count-label and count-number become your column so you have to write css like this

```
#counts-container,
.count 
{
width:400px;
float:left;
}

.count-label
{
   width:150px;
   float:left;
}

.count-number
{
   width:250px;
   float:left;
}
```

{#} for id and
. for class

Comment: -1, because floating elements is NOT the same as table cells.

Comment: Not if they have different heights. Not if the width is less than the content width. Not if a hundred other reasons.

Comment: floating is horrible (IMHO) use it as little as possible (IMHO) (disclaimer: this is IMHO)

Comment: @SonalKhunt please refrain from using "text speak", this is not an SMS; I edited your answer, roll it back if you feel better using "bcm","u","ur"